# Is this sample code that I'm supposed to adapt incorrect

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

So we're working on stacks in my data structures class. Our task is to adapt the following sample code and improve it. The function uses stacks to determine whether a string is a mirror. Meaning something like "abcmcba". Our task is to rewrite this sample to return a more specific reason why it isn't a mirror instead of just true or false. Like if there's a mismatch of characters, an invalid char was used, or if one side is longer than the other. I got it done but I wasn't satisfied with my solution even though it met the criteria so I took another look at the sample and I think I may have found a problem that I would like your help to confirm

```
from Stack_array import Stack

MIRROR = "m"
CHARS = "abc"

def is_mirror(string):
    mirror = True
    stack = Stack()
    n = len(string)
    i = 0

    #pushes all values in string to a stack
    while i < n and string[i] != MIRROR:
        if string[i] in CHARS:
            stack.push(string[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            mirror = False

    # skip over the mirror character
    i += 1
    #Compares left and right sides by popping stacks.
    while mirror and i < n and not stack.is_empty():
        c = stack.pop()

        if string[i] != c:
            mirror = False
        else:
            i += 1

    # check final conditions. Will check if one side is longer than the other. 
    if not (i == n and stack.is_empty()):
        mirror = False
    return mirror
```

The final if statement is where I see a possible error. If i is not equal to the length of the string and the stack isn't empty that means one side is longer than the other. the problem? In the while loop above it if we find that mirror is false prior to reaching the end of the string we'll stop incrementing i and stop popping values from the stack. Meaning that if I'm correct "if not (i == n and stack.is_empty()):" will ALWAYS trigger even if both sides in fact have equal length. In the example above this works out fine since it's false either way. But if we want more specific results like one side being longer than the other then the if statement will evaluate true and mirror will be overidden.

As an example

```
from Stack_array import Stack

MIRROR = "m"
CHARS = "abc"

def is_mirror(string):
    mirror = True
    stack = Stack()
    n = len(string)
    i = 0

    #pushes all values in string to a stack
    while i < n and string[i] != MIRROR:
        if string[i] in CHARS:
            stack.push(string[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            mirror = "Invalid char"

    # skip over the mirror character
    i += 1
    #Compares left and right sides by popping stacks.
    while mirror and i < n and not stack.is_empty():
        c = stack.pop()

        if string[i] != c:
            mirror = "Side character mismatch"
        else:
            i += 1

    # check final conditions. Will check if one side is longer than the other. 
    if not (i == n and stack.is_empty()):
        mirror = "Side length mismatch"
    return mirror
```

And we feed it the string "abmcb
If we have a side character mismatch then i<n and the stack won't be empty. So then the side length mismatch result will override the character mismatch result even though the side lengths are in fact equal

This means that we'd need to fix this and ensure that the final check only runs if everything else is clear and we haven't hit any other errors so far. The specs for this adaption also say that the check only happens if everything else so far is clear. Is my hunch right?

Simply adapting the code to add special conditions doesn't work. I believe this is because of an error made by the professor involving an if statement and incrementation of variable i

Comment: Isn't it problematic that the letters must be "a", "b" or "c" and the middle character must be "m"? If the task really is (quote) *"to determine whether a string is a mirror"*, then surely a string can have different characters and still be a mirror of itself... This is not very generic, and the first improvement that comes to mind is to make it generic.

Comment: Secondly, if you are allowed to access any character in the input string with `string[i]` why do you need a stack at all? I don't get it... this seems overly complicated with no visible gain. You don't need dynamically sized memory (like a stack) to see if a string is a mirror of itself.  It is hard to answer a question about improvements when apparently there are (silent) requirements to **not** improve it.

Comment: @trincot. 

1. There's specific improvements we have to make. Specifically just returning whether or not the string is a mirror and WHY

2. It's a first year CS course. At this stage it's more about whether it can be done rather if it SHOULD be done. It's just meant to make us think about how stacks work.

In addition to the issue I mentioned I'm pretty sure that first loop will repeat forever if  the if statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- In the first loop, when `mirror` is given a value, the loop continues and the loop condition will never change. Instead, the loop (and function) should exit.
- In the second loop the loop condition includes `mirror`, but if all is well so far, `mirror` will be False, so the second loop will not execute. This should not be a condition of the loop.

Not a problem, but:

- When `mirror` is given a value, the loop still continues. It would make more sense to exit the loop (and function) when a mismatch has been detected.
- It is not good practice to have a function that can return different data types: sometimes `False` (boolean), sometimes a string. I would always return a string. If not problem is found, it could be "ok" or the empty string.
- Shouldn't there be a check that "m" really occurs in the string and if not this is given its own reason?

Here is a correction:

```
MIRROR = "m"
CHARS = "abc"

def is_mirror(string):
    stack = Stack()
    n = len(string)
    i = 0

    while i < n and string[i] != MIRROR:
        if string[i] in CHARS:
            stack.push(string[i])
            i += 1
        else:  # return when something is wrong
            return "Invalid char"

    if i == n:  # A separate reason
        return "Center character ('m') not found"

    i += 1
    # `mirror` is not a loop condition
    while i < n and not stack.is_empty():
        c = stack.pop()
        if string[i] != c:  # return
            return "Side character mismatch"
        i += 1

    if not (i == n and stack.is_empty()):
        return "Side length mismatch"
    return "ok"  # Don't return a boolean
```

It should be said that using a stack for this problem is overkill. Secondly, in Python a `for...in` loop is preferred over a `while` with a body that increments an index variable.

Comment: One of the checks we were responsible for implementing ourselves as part of improving the program was in fact a check to determine if the mirror character "m" even appeared at all

I believe that the reason it originally checks for if mirror is true in the second loop is because we only proceed with the rest of the checks if everything is good so far. If we're previously detected an error then there's no reason to continue on. We know it's bad.

Comment: OK, but your code didn't check if the "m" was absent. If it was absent, then `i == n` after the first loop and that would be the reason why the second loop would not be entered and the returned message would be "Side length mismatch". With this correction, that condition is checked (`i == n`) and a specific message is returned when "m" is not found.

Comment: correct. This code does not check if m is absent. This is the example code made by the professor that we're supposed to build off. My question is whether this example code has errors in it. Specifically in regards to that final if statement  overriding any other results. I believe it does as in my own code I've implemented my theorized fixes and everything works as it should not. In *my* code I've done all the checks like that

The code I posted is the simple example code we're supposed to expand upon. Hence why it only returns True or False instead of specific reasons. That's up to us.

Comment: The original code is correct, as it doesn't need to distinguish the *reason* for the mismatch. It could have been more optimal, as there is no reason to continue the first loop when `mirror` is set to `False`. But in your version (I assumed the second code block was yours? If not, which one is?) I suppose it was intended to raise a specific message when the "m" was not found, and this doesn't happen in your code. In both versions of the code it makes sense to immediately *return* out of the function once something is detected that makes the input not a mirror-pattern.

Comment: Anyway, I think in my answer I have pointed out what the problems are in the *second* code block you have in your question: it is not correct, which I understand was your question.